# How to find how many times a particular ip appears in a log file?

Tags: python, ip-address, python-2.x

I have a python script which extracts unique IP addresses from a log file and displays their count of how many times those IPs are pinged the code is as follows.

```
 import sys

 def extract_ip(line):
     return line.split()[0]

 def increase_count(ip_dict, ip_addr):
     if ip_addr in ip_dict:
        ip_dict[ip_addr] += 1
     else:
        ip_dict[ip_addr] = 1

 def read_ips(infilename):
     res_dict = {}
     log_file = file(infilename)
     for line in log_file:
         if line.isspace():
            continue
         ip_addr = extract_ip(line)
         increase_count(res_dict, ip_addr)
     return res_dict

 def write_ips(outfilename, ip_dict):
     out_file = file(outfilename, "w")
     for ip_addr, count in ip_dict.iteritems():
         out_file.write("%5d\t%s\n" % (count, ip_addr))
     out_file.close()

 def parse_cmd_line_args():
     if len(sys.argv)!=3:
         print("Usage: %s [infilename] [outfilename]" % sys.argv[0])
         sys.exit(1)
     return sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]

 def main():
     infilename, outfilename = parse_cmd_line_args()
     ip_dict = read_ips(infilename)
     write_ips(outfilename, ip_dict)

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

I want to add a functionality to the code so that if we pass a particular URL, it should return how many times the URL was accessed by which IP addresses.

E.g. if I pass the url as input: http://www.epicbrowser.com/hrefadd.xml

the output should be in the following format

```
10.10.128.134        4
10.134. 222.232      6
```

The log file is in the following format with 24k lines.

```
220.227.40.118 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
220.227.40.118 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /hrefadd.xml HTTP/1.1" 204 214 - -
59.95.13.217 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /dbupdates2.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
111.92.9.222 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
120.56.236.46 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /hrefadd.xml HTTP/1.1" 204 214 - -
49.138.106.21 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /add.txt HTTP/1.1" 204 214 - -
117.195.185.130 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
122.160.166.220 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense.  Please explain _"how many times an IP address is pinged to the url we passes"_

Comment: @JimGarrison, i have hope that i have edited the question to have better understanding of the problem.

Comment: @Raju.allen: could you please post an example of the log file that is used as input (perhaps a toy example with any personal information removed?)

Comment: @DavidRobinson, i have included example of the log file.

Comment: You still need to explain the question more clearly. With *this specific snippet*, what would be an example of a good input and output?

Comment: @DavidRobinson, the output file will be looking like this
  No.Of Times     Ip
    3        117.196.48.129
    5        117.201.190.198
   20        120.60.34.21
    3        58.97.157.244
    3        49.156.81.51

that is 117.196.48.129 occurs 3 times in the input file, which means  the 117.196.48.129 is pinged into epic 3 times.

Comment: Raju- again, with *this specific snippet.* I don't see 117.196.48.129 appearing three times, or indeed at all, in that snippet, nor do I see any reference to "epic"

Comment: @DavidRobinson, this was a first few lines of the sample input log file and first few lines of the sample output file. the actual input log file is 243607 lines and the actual output file 20721 lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, do not reinvent the wheel, but use the [Counter](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object.

Secondly, use `re.match()` to extract the IP addresses - this way you do not need to handle lines that don't have to process lines that don't have a parseable IP address differently.

Something like;

```
import re
from collections import Counter

cnt = Counter()
ipre = re.compile(r'^(?P<ip>(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])) - -')
with open(infilename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        m = ipre.match(line)
        if m is not None:
            ip = m.groupdict()['ip']
            cnt[ip] += 1
```

Comment: but how do i use this in my python code? sorry, i'm new to python.